# Can't figure out why My Onclick method doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

Can anyone please tell me why clicking on my RecyclerView items doesn't do anything ?
I've tried everything
This is my adapter class

```
public class MessagePosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessagePosAdapter.MessViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<MessUploadModel> messuploadModels;

public MessagePosAdapter(Context context, List<MessUploadModel> messuploads) {
    this.messuploadModels = messuploads;
    this.context = context;



}

@NonNull
@Override
public MessViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.messagesrecv, viewGroup, false);
    MessagePosAdapter.MessViewHolder viewHolder = new MessagePosAdapter.MessViewHolder(v, context);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessagePosAdapter.MessViewHolder messViewHolder, int i) {

    MessUploadModel messupload = messuploadModels.get(i);


    messViewHolder.nameTextV.setText(messupload.getSender_username());
    messViewHolder.titTextV.setText(messupload.getPost_subj());
    messViewHolder.temps.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(messupload.getComment_time(),
            System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS));

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messuploadModels.size();
}


public class MessViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView nameTextV, titTextV, temps;
    /*public ImageView postImageV;
    public CircleImageView prof_image;*/

    public MessViewHolder(View itemView, Context context) {
        super(itemView);

        nameTextV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewNotName);
        titTextV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewNotTitle);
        temps = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewNotTime);
        
        /*postImageV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewPost);
        prof_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewProfile);*/
    }
    
}
```

}

Over here is my ViewHolder
public class MessViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

```
View mView;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyApp_Settings";


public MessViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    mView = itemView;


    //item click
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
    //item long click
    itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            mClickListener.onItemLongClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            return true;
        }
    });

}
public void setMessages(Context context, String notname, String nottit, long time){
    //Views
    TextView NameTv = mView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewNotName);
    TextView NotTitTv = mView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewNotTitle);
    TextView TimeTv = mView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewNotTime);


    /*ImageView ImageViewPost = mView.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewPost);
    CircleImageView circleImageView = mView.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewProfile);
    Button available = mView.findViewById(R.id.Avail);
    Button privmess = mView.findViewById(R.id.PrivMes);*/

    //set data to views
    NameTv.setText(notname);
    NotTitTv.setText(nottit);
    TimeTv.setText((DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time,
            System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS)));

    //Glide.with(context).load(imlink).into(ImageViewPost);


    /*if (!imlinkprof.isEmpty())
    {
        Glide.with(context).load(imlinkprof).into(circleImageView);
    }*/


}


private MessViewHolder.ClickListener mClickListener;

//interface to send callbacks
public interface ClickListener{
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    void onItemLongClick(View  view, int position);
}

public void setOnClickListener(MessViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener){
    mClickListener = clickListener;
}
}
```

This is my main fragment

```
    public static MessageFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    MessageFragment fragment = new MessageFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, container, false);

    mSharedPref = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSharedPreferences("SortSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String mSorting = mSharedPref.getString("Sort", "newest"); //where if no settings is selected newest will be default

    if (mSorting.equals("newest")) {
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        //this will load the items from bottom means newest first
        mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    } else if (mSorting.equals("oldest")) {
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        //this will load the items from bottom means oldest first
        mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(false);
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(false);
    }

    //RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.notrecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    progressbarhor = view.findViewById(R.id.progressbarhor);


    SearchView searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.searchView);

    //set layout as LinearLayout
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    //send Query to FirebaseDatabase
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    //String ImageUploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();

    databaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Comments");

    MessagePosAdapter messagePosAdapter = new MessagePosAdapter(getActivity(), messuploadModels);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(messagePosAdapter);



    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    /*String Name = sharedPreferences.getString("nom", "");
    String Email = sharedPreferences.getString("email", "");
    String Ville = sharedPreferences.getString("ville", "");*/
    String Profile = sharedPreferences.getString("profile", "");



    return view;


}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


    progressbarhor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);





    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String userid = Objects.requireNonNull(user).getUid();




    Query firebaseSearchQuery = databaseReference.orderByChild("receiver_id").equalTo(userid);


    //if(databaseReference.child("sender_id").equalTo(userid)) { }



    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MessUploadModel, MessViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MessUploadModel, MessViewHolder>(
                    MessUploadModel.class,
                    R.layout.messagesrecv,
                    MessViewHolder.class,
                    firebaseSearchQuery


            )

            {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(MessViewHolder messviewHolder, MessUploadModel messmodel, int position) {
                    final String key=getRef(position).getKey();


                    messviewHolder.setMessages(getActivity(), messmodel.getSender_username(), messmodel.getPost_subj(), messmodel.getComment_time());
                    progressbarhor.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                }



                @NonNull
                @Override
                public MessViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                    final MessViewHolder messviewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);


                    messviewHolder.setOnClickListener(new MessViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                            //Views
                            //RelativeLayout addcomm = view.findViewById(R.id.com);


                            //get data from views
                            /*String mTitle = mTitleTv.getText().toString();
                            String mDesc = mDescTv.getText().toString();
                            Drawable mDrawable = mImageView.getDrawable();*/


                            //Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mDrawable).getBitmap();

                            //pass this data to new activity
                            /*Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PostDetailActivity.class);
                            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                            byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
                            intent.putExtra("image", bytes); //put bitmap image as array of bytes
                            intent.putExtra("title", mTitle); // put title
                            intent.putExtra("description", mDesc); //put description*/
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Post_details.class);
                            final String key=getRef(position).getKey();
                            intent.putExtra("key", key);
                            startActivity(intent); //start activity

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), position + key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
                            //TODO do your own implementaion on long item click
                        }
                    });

                    return messviewHolder;
                }

            };


    //set adapter to recyclerview
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);



}
}
```

Everything else works fine. Only nothing happens when I click on items. I've used this method before on numerous occasions and it worked fine. I cannot, for the life of me, figure why it won't work here. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Abhijithmogaveera Do you mean that I need to remove the Onlongclick method ?

Comment: I don't think that's right. You can use both kinds of listeners at once. That link above is for GestureDetector, which you aren't using, and GestureDetector can handle both at once anyway. It's shown in the examples right on that same page.

Comment: @Tenfour04, What do you think the issue is then ?

Comment: You've shown two completely different source codes for your MessViewHolder class. Maybe they both exist in your project and you need to delete the one that doesn't set click listeners.

Comment: @Tenfour04 If you're talking about the fact that I edited my post, that's because I've tried different things to solve the issue, but it's the same file and the same class. I have another  viewholder that's handling another fragment but I've tried to use it for this case too and it didn't work

Comment: Your first code block above includes a MessViewHolder class in it at the bottom which is different from the one in the second code block. If they are both defined in your project at the same time, the one that is closer in scope (the one defined as an inner class of your adapter) is the one being used. I'm theorizing that maybe you forgot to delete that old version.

Comment: I just added an onclick on the class that didn't have it and nothing happened

Comment: It should work. Without seeing your actual code, I can't tell what you did wrong. I recommend completely deleting one of the two classes to avoid any possibility of confusion. Then you can use the debugger with the remaining class to see if its click listener is getting triggered.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).